# How to remove characters/strings/patterns between, before and after some other characters/strings/patterns in a fasta file using a Ubuntu command line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I change all the lines in a fasta file from this:

```
>vsearch_derep1;size=1 331 95 544  TRINITY_DN40607_c0_g1_i1 len=2000path=[0:0-1097]
ATGGGATTAACTGGTAAGTTAATTGCTGCAATAGAGTTTAAGGCTGGTGGTGATGTTTTC
CATGAGCTGTTCAGGCACAAGCCACAACATTTATCCACAGTAAGCTCTGAGAAAGTACAA
```

To this:

```
>TRINITY_DN40607_c0_g1_i1
ATGGGATTAACTGGTAAGTTAATTGCTGCAATAGAGTTTAAGGCTGGTGGTGATGTTTTC
CATGAGCTGTTCAGGCACAAGCCACAACATTTATCCACAGTAAGCTCTGAGAAAGTACAA
```

That means I would like to remove anything between ">"  and "TRINITY_", and anything after "TRINITY_DN40607_c0_g1_i1". Please note that the "1" after "i" varies throughout the fasta file.

I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` like so:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "TRINITY_") {$0=">"$i}}}1' file.fasta
```

If `TRINITY_` is found in a field then replace the whole line with that field preceded with `>` and print all lines ... The above command will not edit the original file `file.fasta` but, will just output the lines ... To get the output in a file like `output.fasta` instead, do it like so:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "TRINITY_") {$0=">"$i}}}1' file.fasta > output.fasta
```

or edit the original file in-place(*the original file will be modified*) with `gawk` like so:

```
gawk -i inplace '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "TRINITY_") {$0=">"$i}}}1' file.fasta
```

Comment: Dear @Raffa , the sed command is working. It is successful. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it

Comment: @Faroll You are most welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `sed` regular expression `\(TRINITY_[^[:blank:]]*\)` to match the longest sequence of non-blank characters after `TRINITY_` and re-substitute in place of the entire sequence description:

sed 's/^>.*(TRINITY_[^[:blank:]]*).*/>\1/' --in-place file.fasta

Comment: Hello @Raffa, thank you for your input. I have copied and passed the sed and awk command line, and replace file. fasta by my fasta file,  but it did not work. The original fasta file remains the same

Comment: @Faroll for `sed`, you can make changes to the file directly by adding the `-i` or `--in-place` options (I recommend something like `-i.bak` to save a backup of the original). GNU `awk` (aka `gawk`) has a similar feature using `-i inplace` - see [Enabling In-Place File Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for replying and sorry to invade your space :-) ... @Faroll Both commands work .. I tested the `sed` command as well and up-voted the answer ... It's just we are very cautious when it comes to other people's data so that it doesn't get edited/overwritten ... That's the reason I steer away from in-place editing unless you ask for it so you know what to expect ... I think @steeldriver does the same too.